# Convert Visual Basic .Net 2.0 program to 1.1 automatically

Tags: .net, version, backwards-compatibility

Here's a pretty silly question, but we want to do this. Is there an easy way to take a 2.0 project or 2.0 source code and convert it back 1.1. Obviously we have the 2.0 source and for compatibility reasons we want to create a 1.1 version. Any thoughts.

Comment: Do you know if you are you using any 2.0-only features?

Comment: but why would you want to do that? D:

Comment: @townsean: compatibility reasons... Can be as simple as targetting a system that does not support .NET 2.0. It's a pity, but sometimes you have to do it.

Comment: I guess I can understanding needing to stick with 2.0 instead of 3.5 or 4, just never thought I would see a situtation where 1.1 was still needed D:

Comment: Automatic is off the table.  Purchase a license for VS2003 or figure out how to compile the project from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eek.

The simplest thing to do would be to add a SupportedRuntime attribute to your XML config. Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx. Be advised that this does NOT guarantee the code will work against the 1.1 framework; it only tells the .NET 1.1 CLR that it can TRY.

A more comprehensive way, which will leave your program hopelessly broken until you fix everything, is to go into the properties of each project in your solution and change the target framework (under the Application tab) to .NET Framework 1.1. Try to build the program; it will likely fail. Resolve the errors that come up, and keep building until it compiles.

Keep in mind that a LOT of low-level program features, such as generics, and framework components providing interop with unmanaged resources, were introduced in .NET 2.0. You may find it infeasible to target 1.1 from 2.0, much more so than, say, if you were trying to go back to 2.0 from 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no automated way but this is how you do it:

Recreate the solution and project files, add your existing source code, clean up any code that does not compile, and you are set to go (or to test, rather).

Might take a long time to accomplish, but that's how you'd do it.

**EDIT:** Applied suggested change in wording

Comment: I Agree but would change this to "No, there is no automated way but this is how you do it..."

Answer (score 0):

If you give it a thought yourself then you will also realize that it's not even logical to have such kind of tool... How the code will change .Net 2.0 specific syntax, API calls and translate it to .Net 1.1... can you think of any such mapping  :)..

The only thing you can hope is to create the project in 1.1 add your class and then try to build it if no API level errors you are good to go...

If your code use Generics and .Net 2.0 specific syntax or features then no use of trying..

Comment: If the code uses generics, yeah, it's a no. But usually syntax-only features work, as long as you use a 2.0 compiler, targetting 1.1.

Comment: His Q's is tag as Backward Compatibility... and ask specifically for converting the code..